# Get Alias using ResultSetMapping

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework, doctrine-orm, nativequery

I have a query that using latitude and longitude, gets me the records that are close to other latitude and longitude. In the query I get the distance but I don't know how to return it. This is my code:

```
public function findNearUsers($lon, $lat, $dist = 25){

        $rsm = new ResultSetMapping;


        $rsm->addEntityResult('Entities\Users', 'l');
        $rsm->addFieldResult('l', 'id', 'id');
        $rsm->addFieldResult('l', 'name', 'name');
        $rsm->addFieldResult('l', 'birthDay', 'birthDay');
        $rsm->addFieldResult('l', 'gender', 'gender');

        $query = $this->_em->createNativeQuery(
                "SELECT l.id, l.name, l.birthDay, l.gender, SQRT(
    POW(69.1 * (latitude - (?)), 2) +
    POW(69.1 * ((?) - longitude) * COS(latitude / 57.3), 2)) AS distance
    FROM users l
            HAVING distance < (?)
            ORDER BY distance", $rsm
        );

        $query->setParameter(1, $lat);
        $query->setParameter(2, $lon);
        $query->setParameter(3, $dist);

        return $query->getResult();
    }
```

As you can see I calculate the distance and have in the query as `as distance` . How can I return `distance`? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anybody that has the same problem, I don't know if it was a workaround, but adding the variable to my entity worked.